# Условная компиляция

Tags: java

А как в Java реализуется условная компиляция?

Скажем, у меня есть TCP сервер. Мне нужно на этапе отладки складывать в файл пришедшие пакеты. Потом, в релиз версии, этот функционал нужно будет отключить.

Как такое принято реализовывать? В Си это делается так

```c
#ifdef DEBUG
  savePacket();
#endif
```

а в Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть ещё один способ эмулировать макросы препроцессора - процессоры аннотаций + Java Compiler API. Этот способ сложнее, но не требует дополнительных библиотек и не выполняет никаких дополнительных действий в рантайме, все изменения в код вносятся в процессе его компиляции, между этапом разбора исходного текста и преобразования его в байткод.

Аннотация для активации отладочных действий:

```
package com.example;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)  // Аннотация существует только до компиляции
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Debug {
    // Чтобы отключать аннотацию, не убирая её
    // но можно и без этого
    boolean value() default true;
}
```

Жертва эксперимента:

```
import com.example.Debug;

public class SomeServer {
    private void savePacket() {
        System.out.println("Packet saved");
    }

    @Debug
    private void receivePacket() {
        System.out.println("Packet received");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeServer srv = new SomeServer();
        srv.receivePacket();
    }
}
```

*Процессор*:

```
package com.example;

import com.sun.tools.javac.model.JavacElements;
import com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment;
import com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree;
import com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeMaker;
import com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context;
import com.sun.tools.javac.util.List;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor;
import javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedAnnotationTypes;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedSourceVersion;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedOptions;
import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;
import javax.tools.Diagnostic;

@SupportedOptions("debug")
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("com.example.Debug")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_8)
public class DebugProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        if (roundEnv.processingOver())
            return false;

        // Получаем параметр указывающий на отладочную сборку
        boolean enabled = Boolean.parseBoolean(
          processingEnv.getOptions().getOrDefault("debug", "false"));

        Context ctx = ((JavacProcessingEnvironment) processingEnv).getContext();
        JavacElements elementUtils = (JavacElements) processingEnv.getElementUtils();
        TreeMaker treeMaker = TreeMaker.instance(ctx);

        // Обходим методы помеченные аннотацией @Debug
        for (Element element : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(Debug.class)) {
            Debug debug = element.getAnnotation(Debug.class);

            if (debug.value() && enabled) {
                JCTree.JCMethodDecl jcMethodDecl = (JCTree.JCMethodDecl) elementUtils.getTree(element);

                // И добавляем в конец метода вызов другого метода
                treeMaker.pos = jcMethodDecl.pos;
                jcMethodDecl.body = treeMaker.Block(0, List.of(
                    jcMethodDecl.body,
                    treeMaker.Exec(
                        treeMaker.Apply(
                            List.<JCTree.JCExpression>nil(),
                            treeMaker.Select(
                                treeMaker.Ident(
                                    elementUtils.getName("this")
                                ),
                                elementUtils.getName("savePacket")
                            ),
                            List.<JCTree.JCExpression>nil()
                        )
                    )
                ));
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Собираем аннотацию

```
$ javac -d build Debug.java
```

Собираем *процессор*

```
$ javac -cp build:"$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar" -d build DebugProcessor.java
```

А теперь собираем SomeServer с использованием *процессора*

```
$ javac -cp build -processor com.example.DebugProcessor -Adebug=true SomeServer.java
```

Или можно собрать сервисный jar и положить в classpath, чтобы *процессор* использовался автоматически. Для этого `DebugProcessor.class` надо упаковать в jar вместе с файлом `META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor` содержащим строку `com.example.DebugProcessor`. Тогда при сборке останется только указывать параметр `-Adebug=true`, когда нужны отладочные действия, и просто не указывать в другом случае.

**P.S.** По-хорошему надо было ещё метод `savePacket` тоже генерировать на лету, но я несколько притомился. Может дополню ответ в другой день.
**P.P.S.** И возможно, напишу ещё третий ответ - про написание плагинов для компилятора.

Comment: Этот вариант мне нравится еще больше

Answer (score 4):

В Java так просто не делают. Если уж очень надо, то самое лучшее (из того, что пришло мне в голову) - это АОП.

**UPDATE:** Покажу пример использования АОП с AspectJ. Для наглядности не буду использовать ни внедрения аспектов контейнером, ни связывания Maven'ом, всё ручками.

Аннотация для активации отладочных действий:

```
package com.example;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Debug {}
```

Жертва эксперимента:

```
package com.example;

public class SomeServer {
    @Debug
    public void receivePacket() {
        System.out.println("Packet received");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeServer srv = new SomeServer();
        srv.receivePacket();
    }
}
```

Аспект:

```
package com.example;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;

aspect DebugAspect {
    // Добавляем в класс сервера метод
    // выполняющий отладочные действия
    private void SomeServer.savePacket() {
        System.out.println("Packet saved");
    }

    // Вызываем добавленный метод при выполнении
    // любого метода помеченного аннотацией @Debug
    @After("@annotation(Debug) && execution(* *(..))")
    public void after(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        SomeServer srv = (SomeServer) joinPoint.getTarget();
        srv.savePacket();
    }
}
```

Создаём в каталоге с исходными файлами подкаталог deps и скачиваем в него aspectjrt-1.9.1.jar, aspectjtools-1.9.1.jar и aspectjweaver-1.9.1.jar.

Выполняем сборку со связыванием

```sh
$ java -cp deps/* org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main -d build -source 1.8 -target 1.8 DebugAspect.aj Debug.java SomeServer.java
```

Запускаем

```sh
$ java -cp deps/* com.example.SomeServer
```

и получаем

```
Packet received
Packet saved
```

Если выполнить сборку без связывания (или убрать аннотацию `@Debug`), будет выведена только строка "Packet received", несмотря на то, что код остаётся неизменным.

Comment: Т.е. разные классы, в которых переопределены какие-то ключевые методы?

Comment: В Java такое не делают, потому, что затея глупая или потому, что нет такой возможности?

Comment: Нет, вы в отдельном классе определяете аспект, который добавляет отладочную функциональность к обычным классам вашей программы. Для отладочной версии программы делаете _связывание_, для релиза нет. Основной код при этом остаётся неизменным.

Comment: Макросы времени компиляции обладают огромным количеством недостатков, плохо укладываются в современные парадигмы программирования и методы разработки, поэтому в современных языках их редко встретишь. Если вообще встретишь.