# Почему у java нет парсера собственного кода?

Tags: java, парсер

Сразу скажу, что знаю, есть, `Javaparser` проект, но он от сторонних разработчиков. Я просто не могу понять если `java` компилируется в байт-код из исходников, то должен быть и **парсер**, разве нет? Под **парсером** я понимаю построение структуры компилируемого приложения, чтобы, например, можно было получить узел определенной переменной по имени. В чем тут подводные камни, если такая фича не предусмотрена(про `javap` знаю, но он работает с байт-кодом, а не исходниками)

Comment: а с чего вы решили, что его нет?

Comment: @michael_best, он про отсутствие парсера в виде класса стандартной библиотеки.

Comment: @Arhad так он есть.

Comment: то есть по-вашему код сам по себе преобразуется в байт-код?

Comment: @michael_best, И чем вас не устраивают классы: `ScriptContext`,
`ScriptEngine`,
`ScriptEngineFactory`,
`ScriptEngineManager`,
`ScriptException`,
`SimpleScriptContext`. Мне прям интересно.

Comment: @michael_best, потому что я его не нашел. Поделитесь знанием, пожалуйста)

Comment: Я вам написал, что нужно, или за вас писать скрипт для компилятора?

Comment: @And почему вы меня упоминаете, я, что, с Вами не согласен?

Comment: @michael_best, ой, я случайно =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У компилятора Java есть [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/tools/package-summary.html). На его использовании построена кодогенерация [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/), например. Примеры его использования есть на Stackoverflow, например [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/844588/204271) и [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/892435/204271).

Comment: Спасибо, ваш ответ помог мне пересмотреть свой вопрос. Я считаю ответ верным, но в итоге я пришел к тому, чтобы использовать `spoon` api

Answer (score 0):

Java написана на C++ (сейчас частично переписывается). Поэтому обеспечить доступ к синтаксическому дереву задача не тривиальная.

А так как это мало кому было нужно, то добавлять эту фичу не стали.

Comment: Сейчас я вам сообщу страшное: Подавляющее большинство лексеров, парсеров, трансляторов, интерпретаторов, компиляторов и виртуальных машин написано на C или C++. Это нисколько не утяжеляет задачу "предоставления доступа к синтаксическому дереву".

Comment: Если не считать необходимости написать классы для всех синтаксических структур, интеграционного кода который будет осуществлять конвертацию, необходимости изменить парсер чтобы он стал реентерабельным и еще кучи всего, то я с вами согласен: совсем не утяжеляет.

Comment: Сейчас я вам сообщу страшное (с), Javac написан на Java (http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/5fa71cce89eb/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/), потому там все впорядке с синтаксическим деревом, вот JVM который интерпретирует байткод написан на C++.

Comment: Похоже я был не прав. Частично. OpenJDK действительно содержит java версию javac, но это не единственная JDK, к тому же это не оригинальный компилятор. Первые версии были написаны на C. Это инвалидирует первую часть моего ответа. Вторая остается валидной.